# Weird output after array is printed in C

Tags: c, output

I am writing a program that takes three numbers, first+second num is the length of each row, second num is the number of rows and third is a 1 or a 0.  So given that the first two numbers are 7 and 4 and if 3rd num is a 1 I want to fill and print the array in the following way:

```
10000000000
01000000000
00100000000
00010000000
```

but when I print it I get weird output following my array:

```
10000000000
01000000000
00100000000
00010000000
��1�
1�
��1
```

Also if I change putchar(arr[i][j]) to printf("%d", arr[i][j]) in the last for loop, the output I get is:

```
4948484848484848484848
4849484848484848484848
4848494848484848484848
4848484948484848484848
-63-1234849-12048700
0400049-964868-55
-41-6500004900016
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening and what I need to do to get the clean output?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *byte_to_binary(int x)
{
    static char b[9];
    b[0] = '\0';

    int z;
    for (z = 128; z > 0; z >>= 1)
    {   
        strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
    }   

    return b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char* tmp;
  int num1, num2, num3;
  int x = 128;
  int i, j;

  num1 = strtol(argv[1], &tmp, 10);
  num2 = strtol(argv[2], &tmp, 10);
  num3 = strtol(argv[3], &tmp, 10);


  int rlen = num1 + num2;  
  char arr[num2][rlen];

  memset(arr, '0', num2 * rlen); 

  // find out if the first number is a 1 or a 0.
  if ((num3 & x) == x) {
   arr[0][0] = '1';
  }
  else {
    arr[0][0] = '0';
  }

  for (i = 1; i < num1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < rlen; j++) {
      arr[i][i] = arr[0][0];
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < rlen; j++) {
      putchar(arr[i][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using Linux, can you run your program with Valgrind?

Comment: Your program does not run: `$ gcc -Wall test.c -o test; ./test` results in `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: You're clearing a `num2*rlen` array, but using `num1*rlen` elements of it.

Comment: @Sneftel Oh, right, thanks, I guess I haven't had enough coffee yet.

Comment: In addition to not running, even if it was valid code, changing `putchar(arr[i][j])` to `printf("%d", arr[i][j])` just changes the representation of what you are looking at, from `char` to `int`. You're not changing the underlying data in `arr`.

Comment: @Stochastic13 BTW, this bug would not have happened if you had given your variables better names than "num2". Remember that the next time you name a variable.

Comment: @Sneftel You're absolutely right, I'll watch it next time.

Comment: @AlexReynolds You have to call it with at least 3 arguments. Otherwise, it crashes trying to access argv.